# How to convert weighted edge list to adjacency matrix in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, graph-theory

Data is present in an excel file with first column representing the first node, the second column representing the second node and the third containing the weight.

The nodes are strings.

Eg:

> Apple Banana 65
>   Orange Apple 32

Comment: I'm sure someone could put it more succinctly but would http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_graph_data_structures.php be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing to do is to import the Excel file. The most straightforward way is to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_excel("path/to/edgelist", header=None)
```

This will return a dataframe of the form

```
In [2]: data  
Out[2]:  
        0       1   2  
0   Apple  Banana  65  
1  Orange   Apple  32
```

**The Short Way: using `networkx`**

Let's first load the networkx package

```
import networkx
```

Then, from `data` we take the edge list as a list-of-lists:

```
edgeList = data.values.tolist()
```

and in this way, we get

```
In [19]: edgeList
Out[19]: [['Apple', 'Banana', 65], ['Orange', 'Apple', 32]]
```

Let's create an empty (directed) graph `G`:

```
G = networkx.DiGraph()
```

and then we add the edges with a simple for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(edgeList)):
    G.add_edge(edgeList[i][0], edgeList[i][1], weight=edgeList[i][2])
```

and we can easily retrieve the adjacency matrix as

```
A = networkx.adjacency_matrix(G).A
```

that reads as a plain and simple `numpy` array

```
In [30]: A
Out[30]:
array([[ 0, 65,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [32,  0,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

**NOTE**: the above adjacency matrix refers to a weighted and directed graph (namely, an edge exist from Apple to Banana, but there is no edge from Banana to Apple). If one needs a weighted and undirected graph (namely, if an edge exists from Apple to Banana, then an edge exists from Banana to Apple), just use

```
G = networkx.Graph()
```

instead of

```
G = networkx.DiGraph()
```

**The Long Way: manually**

Let's take the first and second column in order to gather node IDs

```
nodes = data.iloc[:, 0].tolist() + data.iloc[:, 1].tolist()
```

thus

```
In [4]: nodes
Out[4]: [u'Apple', u'Orange', u'Banana', u'Apple']
```

Let's sort and remove duplicates (sorting is not mandatory anyways)

```
nodes = sorted(list(set(nodes)))
```

and `nodes` now has the form

```
In [8]: nodes
Out[8]: [u'Apple', u'Banana', u'Orange']
```

Let's map each node (string) with a sequential numerical ID to feed the adjacency matrix

```
nodes = [(i,nodes[i]) for i in range(len(nodes))]
```

and `nodes` now has the form

```
In [10]: nodes
Out[10]: [(0, u'Apple'), (1, u'Banana'), (2, u'Orange')]
```

Now that string-to-integer mapping is done, let's replace in the original dataframe (`data`) each string with its corresponding ID

```
In [15]: for i in range(len(nodes)):
    ...:     data = data.replace(nodes[i][1], nodes[i][0])
```

and now `data` has the form

```
In [16]: data
Out[16]:
   0  1   2
0  0  1  65
1  2  0  32
```

So you see that every occurrence of `Apple` has been replaced with `0`, every occurrence of `Banana` has been replaced with 1 and every occurrence od `Orange` has been replaced with 2 (according to the variable `nodes`).

In order to build the adjacency matrix, let's import another well-known package (`scipy`)

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
```

and create a [coordinate-based sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html)

```
M = coo_matrix((data.iloc[:,2], (data.iloc[:,0],data.iloc[:,1])), shape=(len(nodes), len(nodes)))
```

this creates a sparse adjacency matrix (less memory footprint for graphs with many nodes and few edges). If you need a dense adjacency matrix, then

```
M = M.todense()
```

where `M` has finally the form

```
matrix([[ 0, 65,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [32,  0,  0]])
```

**NOTE**: the above adjacency matrix refers to a weighted and directed graph (namely, an edge exist from Apple to Banana, but there is no edge from Banana to Apple). If one needs a weighted and undirected graph (namely, if an edge exists from Apple to Banana, then an edge exists from Banana to Apple), just transpose the above adjacency matrix

```
M_symmetric = M + M.T
```

where

```
In [38]: M_symmetric
Out[38]:
matrix([[ 0, 65, 32],
        [65,  0,  0],
        [32,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: You can shortcut a lot of your getting to your end `data` by `new_df = df[[0, 1]].stack().rank(method='dense').unstack().combine_first(df).astype(int)`