# Construct adjacency matrix with the given List of tuples

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix, bipartite

I have below list of tuples

```
[(772, 36, 3),
 (471, 228, 5),
 (641, 401, 4),
 (312, 98, 4),
 (58, 504, 5),
 (235, 727, 5),
 (285, 266, 4),
 (451, 513, 4),
 (436, 661, 5),
 (101, 648, 3),
 (4, 229, 3),
 (159, 174, 4),
 (832, 1141, 4),
 (53, 544, 3),
 (755, 471, 3),
 (886, 1049, 4),
 (931, 574, 2),
 (641, 582, 4),
 (585, 181, 3),
 (853, 456, 3)]
```

I want to create adjecent matrix using tuple[0] and tuple[1] as matrix dimension and tuple[2] as value inside it.

My code is

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.bipartite import biadjacency_matrix

def to_adjacency_matrix(data,edges):
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    g.add_edges_from(edges)
    partition_1 = set(map(itemgetter(0), data))
    return biadjacency_matrix(g, partition_1).toarray()

to_adjacency_matrix(data,edges)
```

getting exception as TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable at "g.add_edges_from(edges)"

Comment: Can you check `edges` variable , it looks like you need to pass an iterable to `add_edges_from` function, but you are passing an `int`

Comment: type of edge is list, as edges = [tuple(x) for x in data.values.tolist()]

Comment: I think it's because you have 3 elements in your tuples, try it with 2 elements per tuple and it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert weighted edge list to adjacency matrix in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095067/how-to-convert-weighted-edge-list-to-adjacency-matrix-in-python)